# How to use an Icon font for billboard.js chart point rendering

Tags: javascript, charts, billboard.js

[This example shows how to use different kind of points](https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/demo/#Point.CombinationPoints) in billboard.js.

My question is, can you also use some icon fonts as the points?
Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this post it might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930278/how-to-use-more-complex-svg-as-chart-point-in-billboard-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put font icon char value directly, surrounding it by `<text>` node.

Checkout the below example:

```js
var chart = bb.generate({
  data: {
    columns: [
      ["data1", 100, 400, 1000, 900, 500],
      ["data2", 20, 40, 500, 300, 200]
    ]
  },
  point: {
    pattern: [
      "<g><text x='-10' y='40' style='font-family:FontAwesome;font-size:40px'></text></g>"
    ]
  }
});


// In case of don't know set font chars, also can do as
// chart.$.defs.selectAll("text").text(() => '\uf083');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js/dist/theme/insight.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js/dist/billboard.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, added an example: https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/demo/#Point.CustomPointsFontIcon